# RealmChangeListener not working for the first install. Why?

Tags: android, realm

I'm trying to set `ChangeListener` for `RealmResults<Model>` inside a fragment. It does not work only for the first time (Fresh install), after that it works even if the app is killed.

```
onCreateView(...){
        mModelResults = mRealm.where(Model::class.java).findAllAsync()
        mModelResults.addChangeListener(RealmChangeListener {

        })
}

Am I missing something ?
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I changed few things.

(1) Initialized model class in realm database with some data for the first time/install.

(2) Changed `findAllAsync()` to `findAll`.